# android close current activity from WebView

Tags: android, webview

This problem fixed This problem fixed

Answer (score 12):

If you can redirect on button click something

then

```
onClick="document.location.href='http://exitme';".
```

Then in your shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, you can intercept that URL and exit the app.

```
@Override 
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
    if (url.contains("http://exitme")
        finish();  // close activity
    else
        view.loadUrl(url);

    return true; 
}
```

Comment: i get the error "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it." :S

Answer (score 2):

You have to inject `JS interface` in your `WebView`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) is an example, how to catch button click in your `HTML` page and catch this action in `Java (Android)`.

Comment: for that we have to ask our front end team to add java script required code changes to achieve the   `JS interface`

Answer (score 1):

just Call `finish();` inside the Activity class

Comment: the problem with this is that it also close the activity