# How can i close window Android Browser using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, popup

I am developing a site that is used in android webview. the site opens in a pop up. I have to close window the site after 5 seconds. Window.close() don't work android browser. But internet exp, edge works.  what else can I do?

```
function closePopup() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.close();
            }, 5000);
}
window.onload = closePopup();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android close current activity from WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314775/android-close-current-activity-from-webview)

Comment: thanx for your answer. I am developing website. android app is not my work. I should only  window close.

Comment: you tagged `webview` and `android` so I given this answer